# Back button not appearing on navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, navbar

[image]

Above is my storyboard. As you can see, view a and view b are both on the same navigation controller. They are both show segues. The segue to View B is activated manually by a button on the subview on the view of the previous "Home" controller and that works perfectly and has a back button. Here's the code:

```
- (void)storyButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showStory" sender:self];
}
```

The segue to view A is activated manually by an if statement to see if the user is registered:

```
if (currentUser.active != true) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSignUp" sender:self];
}
```

However view A will not show up with a back button even though I'm going about it just like view B. I even tried to add a button to the navbar and manually pop off the view but that button won't even show up! Here's my document outline:

[image]

How do I get my view A to have a back button or at least allow me to add one manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you the segue to A is set to "Show" and not to "Show Detail"?

Also the cancel button in your navBar looks like it might be covering up your button. You might try pinning your cancel button to the right side of your navBar and then seeing if it shows up with a back button.

Comment: I'm sure. Kind is "Show (e.g. Push)"

Comment: Alright then I am sure your cancel button is causing the issue. What happens/or is supposed to happen, when the "cancel" button in your navBar is clicked?

Comment: Well thats the thing, I did everything to get the back button to appear and when it wouldn't I added the cancel button BUT the cancel button isnt even showing up no matter what i do

Comment: What is the type of view, view A and view B are being shown from? It looks like you have a "venue navigation controller", then some other view, and then your view A and view B.

Comment: I think you also need to explain what you are trying to do better. From the looks of it I think your "new" button in your navBar should actually be in your tableView/view B's navBar, and when that button is clicked it should segue "Show" view A, and create the new table cell accordingly. So you would ultimately be segueing from viewB to viewA.  But its hard to tell what your end goal is.

Comment: the view between the nav controller and these two views is a blank view controller which i'm using to add a 3rd party camera  to (LLSimpleCamera).    the camera view has a button on it to show their stories just like snapchat but if theyre not registered to take video then it segues straight to the view a in order to sign up....Yes I know the back button will just pop it back to the camera view like a side step to the sign up but ill figure that out later after i find how to get a back button

Comment: in before you were hidden the navigation bar in previous view controller

Comment: Yes it was hidden in the prior view but I set hide to no on the viewwillappear for view A

Comment: And the navbar does appear